# how hbase random write works

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigtable

I am new to Hbase.Hbase is good for random updates (put or delete) to a table but am unable to understand how hbase performs that.As hbase uses HDFS for its storage and its not possible to update anything in HDFS.
Hbase uses memstore to update the records and writes any edit to the memstore first.So MemStore contains arbitrary number of updated rows in a sorted key order.when it dumps the data to disk to a hfile ,is this hfile is globally sorted with other hfiles.

After dumping all the hfile is the hfile is replicated in HDFS.Same question for the WAL edit log.WAL log file is also replicated in HDFS or not.For every update are we replicating the update to HDFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

these blog posts may help you
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/06/hbase-io-hfile-input-output/
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/06/hbase-write-path/

but basically, you send a put(key, value) that is written to the wal (for recovery) and to the memstore.
When the memstore reaches a threshold the memstore is written in a sorted order to disk (hfile).
after a while you have multiple hfiles on disk. since you know that each file has sorted content, you can perform a (sorted) merge to query your data.

the WAL is just used in case of crash, if your data is in the memstore and the machine crashes the only copy you have is in the WAL. once your data is flushed the WAL containing the memstore data can be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.this blog explained all...
But got one more doubt about sequence file....does every append in sequence file will be replicated to all the blocks.

Comment: That is part of HDFS. HDFS is doing a similar work as HBase. You write the data with an OutputStream. that data is buffered up to a block-size and then once the block has reached that size is replicated to N machines. more or less is how it works, you have to think that everything is immutable so you don't have the concept of "record", when you append something is added in memory and when it reaches a threshold the data is consolidated (in a block) and then replicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot..this question was bursting my mind for the whole day..
From more reading i got its the same HLog instance that was shared by all the regions to write to the wal.I think the wal instance(fsOutputStream) is not closed in between any writes.

Comment: correct each RegionServer (machine) at the moment has a single HLog (Write Ahead Log) for all the region it is hosting. so when you write something to that RegionServer it is appended to the WAL. To ensure consistency the WAL is forcing a sync() to tell HDFS that even if the block is not completed we want that data to be persisted and replicated.

The flush of the memstore to hfile doesn't require the sync because we have the data in the log, so we just rely on the hdfs buffering.